# connect a 12V device to Raspberry pi

Tags: pi-2

I need to connect a 16mm press Push Button Switch flat round Latching Self-locking 1NO 1NC with 12V rating to Raspberry pi3. (https://www.aliexpress.com/item/16mm-Metal-brass-Push-Button-Switch-flat-round-illumination-ring-Latching-1NO-1NC-Car-press-button/32639077602.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dekMKgp). How can I do that without blowing up the pi?

Answer (score 1):

If you'll just connect the switch contacts to the RPi then there should not be any problem.

Schematic for what is on my mind
[image: Button connection]

As button has light (probably led) that **probably** has to be powered by 12V so for that you'll have to connect it by some other means to RPi if you'd like to control that.